# How should I tune SQLite for minimum latency?

Tags: c, sqlite

I've read that SQLite is optimized for throughput with the default settings. What's the best way to tune SQLite for minimum (and preferrably, predictable) write latency instead? I'm looking to keep the latency of a simple update+commit below 10ms in all cases.

I think I need to use WAL and checkpoint on another thread, but I'm not sure if checkpoints will block writers on the main thread.

My application has only a single process accessing the database at a time, so no need to worry about concurrency. It's important that the database isn't corrupted, but durability is not that important (recent transactions can be lost).

Comment: "*I'm looking to keep the latency of a simple update+commit below 10ms in all cases.*" You can't guarantee that even if you're writing directly to and from the file manually. Concurrency still matters because there's only one harddisk, and processes have to share it.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas, can I relax that to 99% of cases?

Comment: Also -- a write to a file usually hits the buffer cache, so I think hitting 10ms latency in almost all cases should be possible, as long as durability is not a requirement.

Comment: @NicolBolas Where did you get the impression that *"there's only one harddisk"*?

Comment: @MattFichman You appear to be discoursing with someone who has yet to emerge from the stone age. That aside, this isn't actually a *programming-related* question as it isn't about a programming concept. Can you imagine if we had to accept Windows-related questions here, simply because Windows is written in C? Find an sqlite forum or mailing list and ask there...

Comment: @Seb: Until there is one harddisk per process and no process is able to access the harddisk being used by another process, my point still stands: drive contention makes it impossible to guarantee anything.

Comment: @NicolBolas Haven't you realised that the OP hasn't specified *what* he's writing to, yet? Don't you think it's possible that it could be an external *harddisk* (or heck, *solid state disk*, since the 90s called and wants their tech back), and as a result could be locked for the process? Where did you get your assumptions from?

Comment: @Seb Hey, I'm not sure why this question was put on hold. It's a question about a library, but it's not asking folks to recommend a library - I already know which library I'm using! There are tons of questions about Postgres and Ruby on Rails on this site, for example. I don't see how this question differs from those questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to get low latency for writes is to do them asynchronously, i.e., don't wait for them to be flushed from the cache.

The [WAL documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/wal.html#performance_considerations) says about this:

> Note that with [PRAGMA synchronous](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_synchronous) set to NORMAL, the checkpoint is the only operation to issue an I/O barrier or sync operation (fsync() on unix or FlushFileBuffers() on Windows). If an application therefore runs checkpoint in a separate thread or process, the main thread or process that is doing database queries and updates will never block on a sync operation. This helps to prevent "latch-up" in applications running on a busy disk drive. The downside to this configuration is that transactions are no longer durable and might rollback following a power failure or hard reset.

To prevent checkpoints from happening in the main thread, use [PRAGMA wal_autocheckpoint](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_wal_autocheckpoint).

But this still can introduce delays because the checkpoint must lock the entire database for the duration of the checkpoint operation. If you cannot live with that, move the checkpoints to some idle time when you can afford them, or allow the WAL file grow to infinite size.

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting. What if I use a "passive" checkpoint? From my reading of the docs, it seems like a passive checkpoint might not lock the whole database, but I'm not sure.

Comment: A passive checkpoint does not lock the database if some other connection is writing. But if the checkpoint gets the lock first, the other connection must wait.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for confirming that.